# spring <c:foreach issue jstl java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl, javabeans

I m doing a small spring project and I have an issue when I try toi show data iterating resultList, resultList is set and foreach loop over 4 times as items there are but giveme an exceptions, after going through I realize that items are retrive but if they were just Object instead of porper cast class Result for this reason It crash when I try to invoke getUrl() method (if I call toString works fine).

that's the controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView home(ModelMap model,@RequestParam(required=false,value="") String name) {

        List<Result> result = googleSearchService.doSearch(name);
        modelAndView.addObject("resultList",result);//<- after debub list is full of Result items
        return modelAndView;
}
```

that's the view

```
<c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="item">
            <li><c:out value="${item.getUrl()}"/></li>  
        </c:forEach>
```

Result class is a inner class:

```
public class GoogleResults {


private ResponseData responseData;

public ResponseData getResponseData() {
    return responseData;
}

public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) {
    this.responseData = responseData;
}

public String toString() {
    return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]";
}



static class ResponseData {

    private List<Result> results;

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Results[" + results + "]";
    }
}


static class Result {

    public String url;

    private String title;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Result[url:" + url + ",title:" + title + "]";
    }
  }
}
```

Trace:

> ava.lang.NullPointerException
>       javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:159)
>       org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:147)
>       org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:157)
>       org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)

Comment: Use <c:out value="${item.url}"/>

Comment: interesting I got that javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Propiedad 'url' no legible para el tipo com.leanupp.researcher.GoogleResults$Result

Comment: Result is a static inner class some problem with that?

Comment: Can you show in the question how it looks like?

Comment: As the class is not public, maybe the problem is that it is simply not accessible

Comment: You are right!!!!!! the class was not public pufffff..... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Result` should be marked as `public`